# How to use Fiddler to capture traffic coming from a flash application?

Tags: flash, ssl, proxy, fiddler

Fiddler is a tool for web debugging which essentially simulates a man in the middle attack. I'm using it to decrypt the SSL traffic coming from my computer. Although I can see everything coming from my browser I don't see any traffic coming from flash applications (a chat app).

I was thinking that maybe flash applications don't use the proxy server I set up in my browser in order to get Fiddler to intercept the traffic?

Oh, I can't use wireshark as it won't decrypt any SSL traffic unless I have the private key of the server, which I don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the Flash applet is using HTTP or HTTPS? Flash can use direct socket connections, which do not run over HTTP or HTTPS, and thus are invisible to a proxy like Fiddler or Charles.

Fiddler can capture any HTTP or HTTPS traffic, regardless of its source, and typically captures Flash traffic with ease. Are you using Firefox, Chrome, or IE to run your applet?

Comment: I ran Wireshark and I see SSL connections. Does that mean the applet is using HTTPS? I am using Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, TLS/SSL doesn't necessarily imply HTTPS because it's possible to run other protocols through the encrypted stream. Having said that, you should see the tunnel itself in Fiddler if the browser is proxying the traffic. Is there a public URL for your app?